# Android set back button to last activity

Tags: android, android-activity, parent, back

I have two activities which I'll call Activity A and Activity B. Activity A and Activity B both have a button that will take them to the final activity. Because I can arrive at the final activity different ways, I cannot just set a parent and navigate back to that. How can I set things so it knows which activity was used last and go back to that one?

Comment: You actually have to *do* something to prevent Android from doing what you're asking. That's default behavior: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: The nav. bar works fine like that but without setting a parent my action bar back button does nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Activity A / B when call C use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityC.class);
intent.putExtra("caller", "ActivityClassName");
startActivity(intent);
```

In your Activity C:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String value = extras.getString("caller");
    startActivity(this, Class.forName(value));
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use intent extras to let activity c know which activity it came from